# Execute external script on server with multiple play 2 framework instances

Tags: scala, cron, playframework-2.0

I have a linux server with three play 2 framework instances on it and I would like to execute regularly an external Scala script that has access to all application environment (models) and that is executed only once at a time.

I would like to call this script from crontab but I cannot find any documentation on how to do it. I know that we can schedule asynchronous tasks from Global object, but I want the script executed only once for the three play instances.

Actually I would like to do the same kind of things as Ruby on Rails rake tasks for those who knows them.

Comment: This is half a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765466/periodic-jobs-when-running-multiple-servers/13766458

Answer (score 0):

Create a regular `action` for this task which will be accessible via http, then you can use ie. `curl` in unix' `crontab` to call that action and it will hit first available instance.

Other possibility is... using `Global` object to schedule the task with `Akka` support. In this case to make sure that only one instance will schedule task, you need to determine somehow which one should it be. If you are starting all 3 instances with specified port (always the same per instance) you can read `http.port` to allow or skip the execution.

Finally you can use database to inform other instances, that task is just executed: all 3 instances tries to execute the Akka scheduler, but before execution the task they can check if this task has still TODO flag. If not, instance sets TODO flag to false and continues execution, otherwise just skips execution this time.

Also you can use filesystem for similar approach: at the beginning of the execution, create flag-file to inform other instances, that, this time they can skip the task.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, but I've already thought to all the methods you described. I was wondering if the there is a cleaner way like using an external script in Scala that could access the whole Play 2 framework environment?