# How to schedule a global period Akka job across multiple processes?

Tags: scala, playframework, quartz-scheduler, akka, playframework-2.1

I'm using Akka in Play Framework instead of a Job, to schedule code to run every X seconds. I have a sort of cluster (running on Heroku, currently on 1 dyno but there might be a few concurrent instances occasionally).

Is there an easy way to make the "job" run every N seconds globally in the entire cluster? I know that Quartz supports out-of-process storage/sync mechanisms e.g. a DB - can I use something similar in Scala?

This is the actor setup that is run on Play start:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    val monitorActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[MonitorLoadJob], name = "monitorLoad")
    Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 10 seconds, monitorActor, Tick)
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765466/periodic-jobs-when-running-multiple-servers/13766458

Comment: @Schleichardt - not quite. I'm specifically asking about Akka (while in the context of Play, but still an Akka question)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [`ClusterSingletonManager`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.1/contrib/cluster-singleton.html).

> For some use cases it is convenient and sometimes also mandatory to
>   ensure that you have exactly one actor of a certain type running
>   somewhere in the cluster.
>
> Some examples:
>
> - single point of responsibility for certain cluster-wide consistent decisions, or coordination of actions across the cluster system

It requires running Akka Cluster but it's made for this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to have an actor running on each node, that waits for a notification message to start this job and from the scheduler broadcast the message to these actors.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a `worker` dyno dedicated to your jobs, using a standard `main` method to schedule your job with Akka.

You can check [this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/run-non-web-java-processes-on-heroku) (for Java, but you'll get the idea for Scala).

Comment: I prefer the solution not to be heroku specific - we're currently just testing the waters with Herkou and would prefer not to increase our lock-in.

Comment: Ah ok. So you'll need to use some Akka remote actors and find a way to store a state somewhere.